# BotDetectCaptcha Stuck in URL Rewrite

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, iis-8

We have a request for the following URL that always gets stuck in IIS on the URL Rewrite module. Eventually, so many of these requests back up that it crashes our sites.

We are using a rewriterules.config file and have the following rule however the url keeps getting stuck. Just wondering if the rule is right -

URL - /项目/T3-blast-blast-fx/BotDetectCaptcha.ashx?get=sound&c=c_default_dnn_ctr23193_dynamicforms_captcha_435f5d28b7d5405fb41703f249afe63c&t=7817e716b7544f79922d4facdd74025a

Rule -

```
<rule name="BotDetectStop" >
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.ashx$" />
    <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="BotDetectCaptcha\.ashx$" />
  </conditions>
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve the problem, but to be on the safe side, make sure the conditions work the way you want using logical grouping - MatchAll or MatchAny. You probably want this:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
```

Also, specify the action that should happen when your rule and conditions are matched. E.g. do you want to redirect that request, rewrite it or for nothing to happen. E.g.

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="seethisinstead.aspx" />
```

or

```
<action type="None" />
```